# Атаман и оттоман

Tags: этимология

Как известно, раньше Османскую империю называли еще Оттоманской. Во-первых, мне бы хотелось узнать, откуда такое разночтение? А во-вторых, пришло на ум: а не родственны ли слова оттоман (то же, что осман) и атаман, то есть предводитель казаков или разбойников?

По идее, слово "атаман" тюркского происхождения, но я могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Атаман, гетман от гета (гата) - охотник, воин нерегулярных сил
и ман - мужчина, начальник. Ватага - от ва(ве) гата - много охотников, отряд. Слова из талышского языка, полагаю, что и роськие.
Джигета - охотник, добытчик, воин из джигов, дзыхов - сегодня абхазы. Бог огня у талышей (огнепоклонников)- Otes- Отеш или Отес, потому и свЯтый- светлый. Ш и Ц- заменяются, например: теле-ш (золотой) и 
теле-ц(золотой).  Поскольку скот главное богатство скотоводов, то и скотница и тельцы означали богатство.
Храм огня в Баку произносится на ново- азербайджанский лад- Аташкях- дом огня.  А папа- попА, поп

Comment: Это все версии. Возможные, но не единственные.

Comment: интересно было бы узнать и другие версии. Для того я и пришел сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В индуистской философии существует понятие **атман** – это высшее Я, центр, вокруг которого формируется сущность. Тюркский **ата**, белорусский **тата**, русский **отец** – слова, происходящие, на мой взгляд, именно от санскритского **атман**. Ведь по сути они схожи: **атман** – создатель и **отец** – создатель. **Атаман** так же является центром, вокруг которого формируется войско, он же может являться и создателем этого войска.
**Осман**(Усман) – это основатель династии, первый султан Османской империи. Его имя означает – **слуга бога**, из чего следует, что божья крупица есть и в этом слове, а значит связь **атмана** и **Османа** не исключена.

Comment: ОТТОМАНКА 
оттоманки, ж. (фр. ottomane из тур. Othman - Осман, соб. имя). Широкий мягкий диван с подушками, заменяющими спинку. 


Буквосочетание th читают разными способами,  как з, с, т, как ф. Как кому удобно в разных языках.
Вот приняли -- Осман, по прозвищу основателя османской империи Османа Гази.
хотя по-арабски عثمان غازي звучит именно как othmen rasli в английской транскрипции.

Comment: >буквосочетание th читают разными способами  
  
В турецком нет сочетания th. Это не английский и не греческий. 
Ни в каком языке "Оттоман" через не пишутся. Это очередные фантазии.
Кстати, и "путается" греческое th только у русских. 
Причина, как сказал, в другом. Имя "Осман" пришло в европейские через арабский. А там Д/Т и З/С действительно путаются. Ср: Рамадан/Рамазан.

Answer (score 1):

*Странно, вроде был тут ответ?! Ладно, я перескажу.*

Не совсем понятно, почему вы называете "разночтением" два названия одного государства. У него еще и третье есть - Порта.  ))) Бывает.   
Что касается происхожения, то видимо "оттоман" - это просто фонетический вариант от Осман, пришедший через арабский, в котором С/З и Т/Д часто смешиваются в силу шепелявости последнего. Хотя наверняка не знаю.

Что касается атамана, то этимология темная. По одной из версий - действительно тюркское, но восходит к "ата" - отец, дед, в то время как оттоман - к личному имени Осман.

По другим происходит от ватага (ватагаман) или к немецкому hauptman - напрямую или через польcкое hetman (= украинское Гетьман). Фасмер, впрочем последнюю версию, отвергает.

Answer (score 0):

Про различие названия Оттоманы/Османы (текст взят из Вики, но выглядит очень убедительно):

> From Middle French Ottoman, from Medieval Latin Ottomanus, from
> Ottoman Turkish عثمان‎ (osman), from the Arabic personal name
> عُثْمَان‎ (ʿuṯmān). Osman is the Turkish spelling of the male Arabic
> given name Uthman.

Я вбил в гугл-переводчик عثمان(там есть арабская озвучка) - вторая буква звучит как th в английском.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, при чем тут гугл-переводчик... В арабском "путаются" звуки Д/Т и З/С, это известно, и звук, аналогичный английскому th, там присутвует, да. Но как это объясняет первую фразу вашего послания?

Answer (score 0):

Не называли. Спустя какое-то время они были девлет-и алийе-и османийе (государство священное османское) и как бы всё. Что касается атамана, то да, это тюркское, у казаков, включая слово "qазаq", полно тюркских слов (и не тюркских тоже, но пришедших через). Ничего нового, всё по учебнику.

Answer (score -1):

С турецких сайтов:

> (Od-man) ateş adam anlamında kullanılmaktadır. Arapça kökenli bir
> erkek ismidir. Osman İsminin en belirgin özelliği duygusal olmasıdır.

Первоначальное из арабского языка "Од-ман" - человек-огонь.
Тут на ум приходит скандинавский бог Один и слово "ман", используемое в европейских языках.

Answer (score -2):

Ата, ота - "отец"; ман, мен - "я" на тюркском. Я отец.